# How to setup ediff to open a new frame with the two comparison buffers

Tags: frames, hooks, ediff

When I issue `M-x ediff-buffers`I'd like ediff to create a new frame with the two buffers (and close this frame when done with the comparison). How can I customise ediff to do so?

I tried

```
(defun leo-ediff-before-setup ()
  (make-frame))
(add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook 'leo-ediff-before-setup)
```

but this sets the initial frame *and* a new frame up for the comparison.

Comment: `make-frame` just creates a frame displaying the current buffer. Is that what you want? Is the current buffer what you want in the new frame?

Comment: I would like ediff  to use the new frame for its buffer-window arrangements plus I want ediff _not_ to fiddle with the window layout in the old frame. Does this make sense?

Comment: Read all of `C-h v ediff-window-setup-function` and go from there.  (You can answer your own question if you get that working.)

Comment: @phils thanks for chiming in! I've just tried to advise `ediff-setup-windows-multiframe` (which is called from`ediff-window-setup-function`) to make a frame before all the setup, but it seems to be already too late: the new frame is made, but ediff arranges the buffer still in the old frame. :-(

Comment: I believe you'll want to write a new function which does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: @phils More trial and error revealed that I forgot to _select_ the new frame. See my answer. - Anyway, thanks for setting me on the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code in the question is that the newly made frame is not selected - and ediff operates on the selected frame. So, correct is:

```
(defun leo-ediff-before-setup ()
  (select-frame (make-frame)))
(add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook 'leo-ediff-before-setup)
```

Of course there's more customisation needed if the frame is to be closed at the end of the ediff session.